# What is the SQL query to find all plotters outside the polynomial boundary specified in the google map?

Tags: sql, math, google-maps-api-3, geometry

My sql query is:-

```
select * from tbl_vehicle 
join tbl_driver 
on tbl_vehicle.pk_vehicle_id = tbl_driver.fk_vehicle_id 
join tbl_location 
on tbl_driver.pk_driver_id = tbl_location.fk_driver_id 
join tbl_company 
on tbl_driver.fk_company_id= tbl_company.pk_company_id 
where tbl_company.Company_name='Kerala' and 
tbl_location.latd <10.194027 and tbl_location.longd < 76.201205 and 
tbl_location.latd >10.194027 and tbl_location.longd < 76.201205 and
tbl_location.latd >10.226975 and tbl_location.longd < 76.375022 and 
tbl_location.latd >10.059987 and tbl_location.longd < 76.775730 and 
tbl_location.latd >10.002248 and tbl_location.longd > 76.778940 and 
tbl_location.latd <9.854925 and tbl_location.longd > 76.584336 and
tbl_location.latd <9.835443 and tbl_location.longd < 76.411473 and 
tbl_location.latd <9.899107 and tbl_location.longd < 76.368070 and 
tbl_location.latd <9.993088 and tbl_location.longd < 76.397007 and 
tbl_location.latd <10.081425 and tbl_location.longd < 76.317492 and 
tbl_location.latd <9.992266 and tbl_location.longd < 76.267905 and 
tbl_driver.active_flag=1;



The following are the boundary conditions of my polynomial:-

                        new google.maps.LatLng(10.194027, 76.201205),
                        new google.maps.LatLng(10.226975, 76.375022),
                        new google.maps.LatLng(10.059987, 76.775730),
                        new google.maps.LatLng(10.002248, 76.778940),
                        new google.maps.LatLng(9.854925, 76.584336),
                        new google.maps.LatLng(9.835443, 76.411473),
                        new google.maps.LatLng(9.899107, 76.368070),
                        new google.maps.LatLng(9.993088, 76.397007),
                        new google.maps.LatLng(10.081425, 76.317492),
                        new google.maps.LatLng(9.992266, 76.267905),
                        new google.maps.LatLng(10.194027, 76.201205)
```

I need to identify all of the plotter which locates outside this boundary. the above sql query is not working. please help me to write the exact query. Any piece of code is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You require 2 techniques for solution

1.Use bounding box for query to eliminate most of the point outside area of polygon
//horizontal Latitude coordinates of polygon

```
var polyLat = new Array();
polyLat[0] = 10.194027;
// etc
polyLat[10] = 10.194027;//First point repeated to close polygon
var polySides = (polyLat.length)-1;//number of points in polygon
//vertical Longitude coordinates of polygon 
var polyLng =  new Array();
polyLng[0] = 76.201205;
//etc
polyLng[10] = 76.201205;//First point repeated to close polygon
//Coordinates for bounding box
var maxLat = Math.max.apply(null,polyLat);
var minLat = Math.min.apply(null,polyLat);
var maxLng = Math.max.apply(null,polyLng);
var minLng = Math.min.apply(null,polyLng);
```

Send coordinates to php

```
var url = "dbtoJSON.php";
url +="?maxLat="+maxLat +"&minLat="+minLat +"&maxLng="+maxLng +"&minLng="+minLng;
```

Then use bounding box coordinates in query. Note using PDO

```
// Get parameters from URL
$maxLat = $_GET["maxLat"];
$minLat = $_GET["minLat"];
$maxLng = $_GET["maxLng"];
$minLng = $_GET["minLng"];
// Prepare statement
$sql ="select * from tbl_vehicle 
join tbl_driver 
on tbl_vehicle.pk_vehicle_id = tbl_driver.fk_vehicle_id 
join tbl_location 
on tbl_driver.pk_driver_id = tbl_location.fk_driver_id 
join tbl_company 
on tbl_driver.fk_company_id= tbl_company.pk_company_id 
where(tbl_location.latd  BETWEEN ? AND ? )AND (tbl_location.longd  BETWEEN ? AND ?)
and tbl_company.Company_name='Kerala' and tbl_driver.active_flag=1";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    // Assign parameters
    $stmt->bindParam(1,$minLat);
    $stmt->bindParam(2,$maxLat);
    $stmt->bindParam(3,$minLng);
    $stmt->bindParam(4,$maxLng);
    //Execute query
```

2. Then use pointInPolygon()  to eliminates points outside polygon.

   ```
    if (pointInPolygon(polySides,polyLat,polyLng,dat.lat,dat.lng)){
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(dat.lat,dat.lng); 
        addMarker(latlng,dat.name);
        bounds.extend(latlng);
     }

    function pointInPolygon(polySides,polyX,polyY,x,y) {
    var j = polySides-1 ;
     oddNodes = 0;
     for (i=0; i<polySides; i++) {
       if (polyY[i]<y && polyY[j]>=y  ||  polyY[j]<y && polyY[i]>=y) {
           if (polyX[i]+(y-polyY[i])/(polyY[j]-polyY[i])*(polyX[j]-polyX[i])<x)  {
               oddNodes=!oddNodes; 
           }
       }
      j=i; }

     return oddNodes;
   }
   ```

See [My demo for this method](http://daviestrachan.co.uk/polygon/JSONMapPolygon.html)

Comment: This is great, but i need to rewrite the code as i am using jsp and java. I have some doubts, why the coordinates are seeded to a php page, var url="dbtojson.php"? and what parameters are obtained from http post? the condition of point which has to be examined from database is "tbl_location.latd" & "tbl_location.longd" and the boundary conditions which has to be examined is defined in the polyLat array itself. So please explain, why the coordinates are sended to a page and what are we obtaining from the page? -Thanks in advance.

Comment: My code is using javascript & jquery `getJSON()` to send coordinates to a php page with MySQL database. You should be able to convert `pointInPolygon()` to java.

Comment: I cannot identify "polyX,polyY,x,y" in the pointlnPolygon() as it is not declared before. what vales have to be assigned to it?

Comment: polySides = sides of polygon,polyX = lat from array index ,polyY lng from array,x = lat of pointx,y = lng of pointY

Comment: ok, so can i use use previously declared "polyLat[]" & "polyLng[]" instead of "polyX" and "polyY" in the  "function pointInPolygon()" ??

Comment: Yes iterate through the array